# How do I prove this binomial identity by just using symmetric property and reversing the upper index?

Tags: combinations, binomial-coefficients

$$
\sum_k\binom{l}{m+k}\binom{s+k}{n}(-1)^k=(-1)^{l+m}\binom{s-m}{n-l},l\ge0,\{l,n,m\}\subset\mathbb{N},\{s\}\subset \mathbb{R}
$$

P.S.

Please use these identities below to prove it

1. Symmetric property

$$
\binom{r}{k}=\binom{r}{r-k}, r\in\{x|x\in \mathbb{R}, x\ge 0\},k\in\mathbb{N}
$$

2. reversing the upper index

$$
\binom{r}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{k-r-1}{k}, r\in \mathbb{R},k\in \mathbb{N}
$$

3. VanderMonde Convolute

$$
\sum_k\binom{r}{k}\binom{s}{n-k}=\binom{r+s}{n},r\in \mathbb{R},s\in\mathbb{R},k\in \mathbb{N}
$$

Update

**I can't eliminate k from the upper index, because the symmetric property can only be used when s+k>0**

Comment: The process seems fairly clear.  Please show what you have tried so we can see where you went awry.

Comment: I can't eliminate k from the upper index, because the symmetric property can only be used when s+k>0

Comment: Start with the second rule: "reversing the upper index".

Comment: Could you please give more details?